# Why is my AMCL node closing when I try to set the use_map_topic parameter?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PROBLEM: I can't get my AMCL node to keep running when I subscribe it to my `/map` topic by setting the `use_map_topic` parameter to `true`.

I first start publishing my `map.yaml` information using the below command:

```
rosrun map_server map_server map.yaml`
```

I then use `rostopic list` to verify that the topics `/map` and `/map_metadata` are publishing, which they are.  I next start my amcl node using the below command:

```
rosrun amcl amcl
```

The `amcl` node starts up, as expected, and prints the below information.  I also verify that the `amcl` node is open and running using `rosnode list` and it shows that `/amcl` is running.

```
[ WARN] [1606378586.662116874]: ignoring NAN in initial pose Yaw
[ INFO] [1606378586.689947081]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1606378586.692868130]: Received a 384 X 384 map @ 0.050 m/pix
[ WARN] [1606378586.701443890]: ignoring NAN in initial pose Yaw
[ INFO] [1606378586.711590685]: Initializing likelihood field model; this can take some time on large maps...
[ INFO] [1606378586.724505768]: Done initializing likelihood field model.
[ WARN] [1606378601.810399414]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 
1606378601.810285 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
```

However, the node isn't subscribing to my `/maps` topic.  According to the [amcl ros wik](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl)i, I need to set my `use_map_topic` to `true`, and it will start subscribing.  So I close my `amcl` node and reopen it using the below command:

```
rosrun amcl amcl --ros-args -p use_map_topic:=true
```

This command gives me the below printout in the command window.  With no explanation, the node just closes.  I am new to using `amcl`, so is there something I am missing?  Shouldn't the node stay open and just keep looking for the `/scan` topic like it did when I just used the `rosrun amcl amcl` command?

```
[ WARN] [1606378851.880883739]: ignoring NAN in initial pose Yaw
[ INFO] [1606378851.902627961]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1606378851.905172130]: Received a 384 X 384 map @ 0.050 m/pix
[ WARN] [1606378851.914856931]: ignoring NAN in initial pose Yaw
[ INFO] [1606378851.925499145]: Initializing likelihood field model; this can take some time on large maps...
[ INFO] [1606378851.937561677]: Done initializing likelihood field model.
00:20~/wanderbot_ws$
```

Linux 5.3.0-62-generic #56 18.04.1-Ubuntu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366410/why-is-my-amcl-node-closing-when-i-try-to-set-the-use_map_topic-parameter?/) by [BesterJester](https://answers.ros.org/users/56384/besterjester/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2020-11-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-28**:\

> ```
> rosrun amcl amcl --ros-args -p use_map_topic:=true
> ```

this seems like you are confusing ROS 2 with ROS 1.

`rosrun` is from ROS 1. It does not accept `--ros-args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to find a viable solution.  Instead of the `rosrun amcl amcl` command, I launched the `amcl` node with the below command:

```
roslaunch turtebot3_navigation amcl.launch
```

Also, in that launch file, I had to add the below line to the list of parameters:

```
<param name="use_map_topic"    value="true"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [BesterJester](https://answers.ros.org/users/56384/besterjester/) with karma: 73 on 2020-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2021-12-14**:
Thanks. This worked for me on ROS `noetic`.